# Using AFL's persistent mode to fuzz large amount of repetitive data

Tags: c, fuzzing, american-fuzzy-lop

I have a program that processes packets of certain size but require a large amount of them
for any meaningful output.

I currently fuzz my program with AFL by receiving a packet from AFL and running it through the system the necessary amount of times.

This is not ideal, since I reuse the same deformed packet multiple times, so I switched to using AFL's persistent mode, wherein it sends me data through a pipe continuously.

The problem is that, AFAICT, this mode assumes that each input is run in isolation, and I want to create a crash that is dependent on a series of inputs.

What is the correct way to fuzz my program?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the data received from AFL as a sequence of packets. This is AFL persistent mode example (comments are stripped):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char buf[100];
  while (__AFL_LOOP(1000)) {
    memset(buf, 0, 100);
    read(0, buf, 100);

    if (buf[0] == 'f') {
      printf("one\n");
      if (buf[1] == 'o') {
        printf("two\n");
        if (buf[2] == 'o') {
          printf("three\n");
          if (buf[3] == '!') {
            printf("four\n");
            abort();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Modified example for your case would be:

```
//#define FIXED_PACKET_SIZE       set to your packet size, assuming all packets have same size
//#define NUM_PACKETS_TO_RECEIVE  set to number of packets you want to receive to get meaningfull output

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char buf[FIXED_PACKET_SIZE*NUM_PACKETS_TO_RECEIVE];
  while (__AFL_LOOP(1000)) {
    memset(buf, 0, FIXED_PACKET_SIZE*NUM_PACKETS_TO_RECEIVE);
    read(0, buf, FIXED_PACKET_SIZE*NUM_PACKETS_TO_RECEIVE);

    unsigned curPacket = 0;
    while (curPacket < NUM_PACKETS_TO_RECEIVE) {
      if (buf[curPacket*FIXED_PACKET_SIZE] == 'f') {
        printf("one\n");
        if (buf[curPacket*FIXED_PACKET_SIZE+1] == 'o') {
          printf("two\n");
          if (buf[curPacket*FIXED_PACKET_SIZE+2] == 'o') {
            printf("three\n");
            if (buf[curPacket*FIXED_PACKET_SIZE+3] == '!') {
              printf("four\n");
              abort();
            }
          }
        }
      }
      curPacket ++;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

AFL works bad for big input sizes - trying to modify all bits takes enormous time. When `FIXED_PACKET_SIZE*NUM_PACKETS_TO_RECEIVE` is big, you should
try not to use fuzzed data for packet parts, that will unlikely result in errors.

Another problem can arise when AFL modifies your test data size - it can do so for some input mutations. Your `read` call should handle these cases.